# Is schema definition available in form widgets for formType generated in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

When a form type corresponds to a model, I see in the form view, it renders "required" class for notnull table field types' label. I was wondering if it in any way uses schema definition? How is it passed?

Like in form_label.html.php, we have

```
<?php if ($required) { $label_attr['class'] = trim((isset($label_attr['class']) ? $label_attr['class'] : '').' required'); } ?>
```

How is $required available in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [*Field Type Options Guessing*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing) section of the the Forms chapter of the Symfony book.

> `required`: The `required` option can be guessed based on the validation rules (i.e. is the field `NotBlank` or `NotNull`) or the Doctrine metadata (i.e. is the field `nullable`). This is very useful, as your client-side validation will automatically match your validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (Symfony 2.0.x), required FormType option does only enable HTML5 client-side validation on the field. It has nothing to do with server-side validation, and less with database schema.

`required` option is set to `true` by default. So you have to explicitely set it to `false` to disable HTML5 validation and required class on the HTML input.

Comment: No, I haven't modified any of the formType Stub, default view renders required client side validation as well as adding required class to the label. So without passing 'required' option, it is actually creating view with "required" form fields.

Comment: again, this doesn't seem to be the case, I have three fields in the database table, 2 of them are NOTNULL and one is NULL. For NULL type, it doesn't render required label and validation, whereas for NOTNULL, validation is rendered as well as label has "required" class. Label has required class means, it renders * after the label text.

Comment: Whta version of Symfony do you use ?

Comment: OK, as i told you, I don't know specific behaviour of 2.1.x version. I think they improved entity or form generation based on schema, that was a bit too light on 2.0.x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17185/discussion-between-pece-and-nitesh)